# php files using apache in phpmyadmin are showing on my computer but not on any other browsers

Tags: apache, scripting, phpmyadmin, localhost

The issue I'm having is that when I work on files in phpmyadmin or save them in the apache htdocs, I can then view my login form I created on my computer. However, whenever I send it to someone else or test it on another device no one can view it.

I'm assuming somewhere I'm not connected correctly to the server but I'm showing that my servers are all running.

For example, if I send my link to someone the error they get is " cannot open the page because it cannot connect to the server."

Any help would be much appreciated. I can't seem to find where the disconnect is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the files for your "website" are only on your local computer. Other people won't have the files in their computer and therefore, they cannot access the website on their own localhost.

If you want other people to access your website, you can host your website online so that all the people can access it.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! How would I go about making sure that my website is showing online so others can access it?

Comment: @genee you need to buy a server, a domain name, make some configuration and you'll be able to publish it to the world. Some google-fu might help here, try looking for `hosting` or `deploying [insert tech]`.